# How to create 3D streoscopic images using MATLAB with image tool?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

How do I create a 3D stereoscopic image from a 2D image using MATLAB?

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried?

Comment: I think it would be easier to create it if you have 3D data, since then all you need is to create 2 projections with different angles of view.

Comment: @carlosdc @Itamar Katz : if I want to see 2D image using 3D glass it seen into 3d image format.. like this. Or any other way can see it with 3 dimension?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either I'm misunderstanding your question (people have already pointed out that it's not clear), or you are misunderstanding the way 3D vision works. You don't "see 2D image using 3D glass". 3D vision is achieved by serving two different images, left image and right image, to the left eye and right eye, respectively. At a fundamental level MATLAB doesn't have anything to do with it.

So, in absence of an easily understandable or coherent question, the best I can do is assume you want something like [this](http://make3d.cs.cornell.edu/): you have is a single 2D image, but you still want to "seen into 3d image format".  In that case, you need to somehow split that single image into two new images:

1. Left image for the left eye
2. Right image for the right eye

This isn't trivial.  Generally, you start by [inferring the depth](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asaxena/learningdepth/) of each pixel in the 2D image.  Since you're "guessing" the depth information, the two new images won't be a perfect representation of a 3D scene.

Next, you separate your image into layers using that depth information.  It will essentially look like a pop-up cutout from a children's book:

[image]

The more layers you can come up with, and the more accurate your depth estimation is, the more realistic your 3D representation will be.

Finally, you project that layered representation back onto 2D from two different positions -- one for the left eye, and one for the right eye.  This gives you the two different images you needed.

**EDIT**

The second [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_JRHtHpuSY) you linked to describes the *simplified* creation of what is commonly known as an [anaglyph image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_image).  It requires 3D red-cyan glasses -- these are **not** the polarized glasses they use in most 3D theaters now.  The reason I say *simplified* is that it doesn't discriminate between the foreground and background.

For best effect, you'd separate the foreground from the background, and apply the approach only to the foreground.  This is because typically background has infinite depth and doesn't change when going from mono to stereo vision.  In the case of the piano, everything is more or less foreground, so the approach works.

The algorithm the video describes is:

- Start with two images, `im1` and `im2`.  They are identical
- Set the green and blue channels of `im1` to zero.  This will create the red image
- Set the red channel of `im2` to zero.  This will create the cyan image.
- Offset the two images by some specified amount (depending on the depth to subject) such that `im1` is on the left and `im2` is on the right.  You need to get this order correctly because 3D red-cyan glasses have red on the left, and cyan on the right.
- Perform element-wise addition of the two shifted images.  Note that no channels will saturate.

Here's some Python/OpenCV code I wrote:

```
import cv
SHIFT=8

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    _, fname = sys.argv
    im  = cv.LoadImage(fname)

    size = cv.GetSize(im)
    width, height = size
    left  = cv.CreateImage(size, im.depth, im.nChannels)
    right = cv.CreateImage(size, im.depth, im.nChannels)
    anaglyph = cv.CreateImage((width - SHIFT, height), im.depth, im.nChannels)

    #
    # This would be easier if we had COI support for cv.Set, but it doesn't
    # work that way.
    # OpenCV uses BGR order (even if input image is greyscale):
    # http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html
    # red goes on the left, cyan on the right:
    # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_image
    #
    b = cv.CreateImage(size, im.depth, 1)
    g = cv.CreateImage(size, im.depth, 1)
    r = cv.CreateImage(size, im.depth, 1)
    cv.Split(im, b, g, r, None)

    zeros = cv.CreateImage(size, r.depth, 1)
    cv.Merge(zeros, zeros, r, None, left)
    cv.Merge(b, g, zeros, None, right)

    #
    # cvRect is ( x, y, width, height ) and it MUST be a tuple, not a list
    # 
    cv.SetImageROI(left,  ( SHIFT, 0, width - SHIFT, height ))
    cv.SetImageROI(right, ( 0,     0, width - SHIFT, height ))
    cv.Add(left, right, anaglyph, None)

    cv.SaveImage('anaglyph.jpeg', anaglyph)
```

Here's a similar image to what's used in the video:

[image]

Here's the output:

[image]

Unfortunately I don't have 3D red-cyan glasses to verify that this works.  But it seems like it should, at least in theory.  Perhaps somebody can correct me if I've made a mistake.

Comment: thanks a lot @misha .. but I want like that see the video links http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3r4M_KHt6aw , http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_JRHtHpuSY ,  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdXxS2KHXlo like that .. - thanks Abhi.

Comment: Basically, the first link described pretty much what I did.  Calculate depth map, make second image.  I'm not sure about the actual displace filter implementation.  The second link isn't really all that relevant -- it's not a stereo image, it just achieves a pseudo-3D effect.  If this is what you want, then it's fairly simple to implement, just do exactly as that kid was saying in the video.  I might watch the third video later -- it's a bit long, and it's late here.  Put the relevant link in your original question to make it obvious what you want.

Comment: Thanks @misha yes you get. I want to add pseudo-3D effect from 2d image. I just achieve simple 3d effect as per the video links.                                                               If you have code regarding it reply me.. - Abhi

Comment: So what you want is in the second video -- youtube.com/watch?v=g_JRHtHpuSY ?  I updated my answer with some OpenCV source.  Shouldn't be hard to port to matlab -- I'll leave that to you.

Comment: @misha, i am new to matlab,can you tell me how to execute your code in matlab?

Comment: hi! awesome script. can you provide a way to do it in OPENCV 3?

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier to do if you have two images taken from slightly different points of view.  You can create a stereo anaglyph by rectifying the two images. The relevant functions are `estimateUncalibratedRectifiation` and `stereoAnaglyph` in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.  See the [Uncalibrated Stereo Image Rectification](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/uncalibrated-stereo-image-rectification.html) example.

Alternatively, you can calibrate your cameras using the [Stereo Camera Calibrator app](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/stereo-camera-calibrator-app.html), and then use the `recifyStereoImages` function. See the [Stereo Calibration and Scene Reconstruction](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/stereo-calibration-and-scene-reconstruction.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer.. if we have only one image then can we make stereoscopic image??