# How to create polarized 3D image using Matlab?

Tags: c#, matlab, image-processing, image-manipulation

I want to create polarized 3D image using Matlab or C#?.
Is any way to create 3D image from any 2D image using Matlab or C#?

Comment: How is this different from your last question on this topic?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720857/how-to-create-3d-streoscopic-image-using-matlab-with-image-tool

Comment: my last question was about Create stereoscopic image using matlab. and This is about polarized image there are different 3D technologies for viewing 3D image. There are two different Glasses 1) polarized glass 2) red cyan glass. so they is differs

Comment: This question makes me laugh.

Comment: @Ross I just want added some virtual effect to images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Polarized 3D is an effect created in the **physical world** with **physical projectors** shining onto the same spot of a **physical screen**. It's not a digital effect that you can create in an image on a computer screen. You cannot write code to render an image onto a normal computer screen then see 3D with the polarized glasses.

Comment: You might want to keep this answer on your clipboard, I have a feeling it's going to pop up quite often...

Comment: Yes, if you **project it** onto a **physical screen** with **two projectors**. Do you have **two projectors** you can connect to your computer and a **projector screen** to point them at? If not, then **no, you cannot look at any image on your computer screen and see 3D with polarized glasses.** I'm sorry if my answer was somehow unclear about that...

Comment: Maybe there's still some confusion. You need **two** [video projectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_projector), for example [these](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/category.aspx?c=us&l=en&cs=04&s=bsd&~ck=anav&category_id=5188) or [these](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/BuyEpson/ccProductCategory.jsp?BV_UseBVCookie=yes&oid=-16762) along with the proper lenses.

Comment: You also need a proper screen for that. The screens usually installed are scattering the light, loosing its polarization. What you need is a silver/metallic screen. You can do it DIY, did that a few months ago https://brezn.muc.ccc.de/~joe/datenwolf_leinwand

Comment: @datenwolf - I'd forgotten about that

Comment: @Josh: Epson projectors use LCD technology. If the polarization plane of all the prime colours come out identical, they can be used for circular polarization, by simply adding a &lambda;/4 retarder. One can increase the contrast using a &lambda;/2 plate for rotating the linear polarization plane beforehand.

Answer (score 6):

Stereoscopic images for use with polarised glasses are created by projecting the left and right eye images so that they overlap through separate projectors which have a polarising filter fitted.

The same is true for the red and green **tinted** glasses (which are not the same as the old style [anaglyph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_image) images).

If you only have one 2D image you cannot create a 3D image from it without getting involved in manual image processing.

Comment: Ok Mr. @ChrisF Thanks,If I have 2 separate images for left & right eye too, then How it can possible? any Idea?

Comment: @Abhishek - then you need to **project** them through polarising filters.

Comment: How it possible in matlab? I have polarized glass.but I confused in glasses there are two type of polarizing technique one is Linear & circular polarization. Is the glass works in both polarization techniques?

Comment: @Abhishek - the glasses will only work with compatible filters.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF, How to overlap two separate images using matlab or C#? for view 3D effect? please help me..

Comment: @Abhishek - you don't overlap the images in Matlab if you are using projectors and polarising filters. You create 2 separate images and then project them **separately** through two projectors which are aligned to exactly overlap their images.

Comment: Thanks @chrisF. Is it possible in static Jpg/Png image?

Comment: @Abhishek - if you want a single image that has 3D information encoded into it you need to look at red/green [anaglyph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_image) images.

Comment: @chrisF I know about 3D image create using red/cyan glass from 2 separate images, but how to create 3D polarized image and watch it by using polarized glass... just launched movie sanctum 3D, I seen movie by wear polarized glass. Have you watch that movie.Good movie see it..

Comment: @Abhishek: Guide for building DIY polarized projection system: Buy two identical video projectors emplyong DLP technology (some LCD/LCOS also work, but DLP puts you on the safe side). Make a DIY silver screen by painting a paint made from aluminum powder pigment and clear acrylic base on a black dyed canvas. Take the filters from 3D glasses to make filter slides for the projectors. Connect projectors to dual output video card. Play stereoscopic movie so that each eye is displayed on the apropriate projector.

Answer (score 4):

## Build your own Polarized Stereoscopic Projection System

### Principles of Polarization Optics

#### Polarized Light

Since the late 19th century we know, that light can be described in terms
of electromagnetic waves. The theory behind it are the well understood
Maxwell Equations. Since this is not an article about electrodynamics just
the essentials:

- Light is electromagnetic radiation with wavelenghts between 800nm (red) to 400nm (violet).
- Electromagnetic radiation has an electric and a magnetic field component.
- The electric and magnetic field are transversal, which means perpendicular to the propagation of the wave.
- The electric and magnetic field are perpendicular to each other.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation

The electric field vector (one could also use the magnetic field, but convention
is to use the electric filed) determines the polaization. There are two kinds of
polarization:

- Linear polarization: The electric component remains in one single plane, the polarization plane
- Circular polarization: With each cycle the electric component "swings" into different direction
  If you look along the propagation the field vector may cycle through:

  - ↑→↓← -- this is called **right turning polarization**
  - ↑←↓→ -- this is called **left turning polarization**
    The effect of circular polarization is created by retarding one component
    of linear polarized light by a quarter of a wavelength.

See also this Wikipedia article
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_(waves)

#### Creating Polarized Light

Wikipedia has an excellent article on the details
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer

Here's the essentials.

**Linear Polarization**

Linear polarized light can be obtained in various ways:

- By filtering out all unwanted polarization components
  from light with a broad polarization  distribution.
  All light emitted in a statistical manner (thermic radiation, 
  high pressure gas discharge, lighting arcs) has this property.
  One can filter the desired polarization plane using a filter.
  The following filters are known:

  - **Brewster Beam Spliters** use brewster reflection to split
    a beam of light into two polarization components, polarized
    perpendicular to each other.
  - **Birefringence** employs the phenomenon that some crystals
    have different indices of refraction for different polarization
    planes. Again the light ways are split.
  - **Absorption in strechted polymers**. Stretching a polymer gives
    it an anisotropic structure. Some anisotropic polymers will absorb
    only incoming light polarized parallel (or perpendicular, it
    depends on the material) to the strechting direction.
- The light emited from a laser is linear polarzied.
  Depending on how the laser is built, the polarization plane will
  gradually change over time.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_polarization

**Circular Polarization**

In optics, circular polarization is created by passing linear polarized
light through some anisotropic material, that will retard one of the
components (electric or magnetic) by a quarter of the wavelength. This
is called a **λ/4 retarder**.

The angle between linear polarization and the anisotropic material's major
axis determines ratio between left and right turning polarized light resulting:

- Incoming linear polarized light tilted by +45° will be fully left turning.
- Incoming linear polarized light tilted by -45° will be fully right turning.
- Incoming linear polarized light tilted by 0° will consist of 50% left and 50% right turning.

It should be noted, that due to the reversibility of the light's way the
passing of circular polarized light through a λ/4 retarder will
turn it into linear polarized light of the corresponding certain polarization
plane. This linear polarized light can the be filtered again by linear
polarizers. This is, how circular polarization 3D glasses work.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_polarization

#### Polarized Light and Interaction with the Screen

**Scattering and Diffraction**

The typical projection screen uses very small particles, usually they're TiO2,
to scatter and diffract the light into all directions. In the scattering process
the light bounces multiple times between the particles. While each bounce leaves
a light wave solition polarized in the grand statistical scheme any notable
polarization is lost.

Thus **a normal white projection screen is unsuitable** for polarized stereoscopic projection.

**Metallic Reflection**

The key for building a polarizing stereoscopic projection system is the use
of a screen material that retains the polaization of the incoming light.
This is achieved by employing metallic reflection on particles much larger than
the light's wavelengths.

### A DIY Stereoscopic Projection System

#### Making a DIY Silver Screen

You'll need:

- aluminum powder pigment
- clear acrylic base
- deep black textile dye
- canvas

This is how you do it:

1. Dye the canvas deep black. This will absorb any light not reflected,
   instead of scattering it. Let it dry thorougly. You may repeat step 1
   multiple times.
2. Paint one layer of clear acrylic base on the now deep black dyed canvas.
   Doing it one side suffices. All futher steps are now done on this clear acrylic base.
3. Make a very thick aluminum acrylic paint. Here are a few hints:

   - Mix the aluminum powder with the acrylic base in very small batches.
     Don't make a aluminum power paste by mixing it with water!
   - After putting each small batch of aluminum powder into the acrylic
     stir thoroughly so that it is a homogenous mass.
   - You should end up with a 1 part aluminum powder to 1 part acrylic base paint
   - Once you've got that thick paint, thin it with 1 part of water.
4. Apply layers of aluminum acrylic paint on the prepared canvas. Let each layer dry.
   Repeat step 4 until you've got an **even** aluminum metallic painted surface with no
   black parts shining through.

#### Video Projection

**Single Projector Setup**

Most cinemas are using a single projector and the RealD Z-filter system to
alternating show left and right images at a swap rate of 144Hz, where the
Z-filter is dynamically modulating the polarization.

Technically the Z-filter is just some large Liquid Crystal Panel. LCs have the
property, to rotate the passing light's polarization plane, depending on a voltage
applied on the LC. The Z-filter thus rotates the light by +/-45°, controlled
by an AC voltage in sync with the left-right-image swap. Before the Z-filter
is a linear polarizer, behind it a λ/4 retarder, in parallel to the linear
polarizer. The Z-filter will rotate the polarization plane to that either only
left or right turning polarized light is leaving the system, if there's stereoscopic
material shown.

If the Z-filter is turned off, the light will be turned into 50% left and 50% right
turning polarization.

It is perfectly possible to recreate this system DIY. This however shall be described
in a separate article still to be written.

**Dual Projector Setup**

Using two projectors is the most easy way to project the distinct polarized images.
The idea is simple: Each projector is equiped with a polarizing filter matching the
filter in the viewer's glasses eye filters, so that light projected from the "left"
projector will reach only the left eyes, and the "right" projector's light reaches
only the viewer's right eyes.

**Selecting the Projectors**

It boils down to the following: You need two identical projectors which emit either
unpolarized light - that are DLP projectors using classical arc lamps -
or evenly linear polarized light for all base colours.
The later case is more appealing since you'll not "throw away" light. But the safer
is, choosing some DLP type. Note that those new nifty LED projectors usually exhibit
some uneven polarization, which makes them tricky to next impossible to use for
polarized stereoscopy.

**Making the Filter Slides**

The projector's filter slides can be made from the very same kind of 3D glasses
which are worn by the viewers. The 3D glasses of RealD are meant for single use.
Although cinemas setup boxes for recycling, there's no harm to the venues if you
put those glasses you got in the cinema to your own use. In fact most cinemas will
have no problem with giving you some of the glasses returned to the recycling boxes.

You may be tempted to just put those filters right behind the projectors lens.
This is however crude and will quickly destroy those filters. Remember that 50% of
the lights power may end up in the filters, heating them up.

So you want to distribute the light's power over a significant large area.

You'll need:

- a number of used RealD glasses
- 4 panes of identically sized picture frame glass (something like 50mm × 50mm)
- sharp and exact scissors or a paper guillotine
- a fine tip water solvent marker pen (or similar) - whiteboard markers do fine!
- some adhesive tape. Duct tape works very well (what, did you expect something else?)

This is how it goes:

1. In all the 3D glasses mark the back side (i.e. the side towards the eyes)
   with a small letter 'L' or 'R' (left eye or right eye), right in the middle.
2. By applying some twist/torque on the glasses frames you can separate RealD glasses
   releasing the filters.
3. Sort the filters into left and right filters.
4. Cut the filters into equally sized rectangular pieces sort them into left and right.
   Don't make them quadratic. It's important that you still know the orientation within
   the glasses' frame.
5. Clear the marking, making sure you still know what's front and what's back.
6. Arrange the filter pieces on the glass panes so that they nearly fill it. Of course
   all facing the same (i.e. all front or all back).
   Keep the gaps as small as possible.
7. Apply the second glass pane, apply the duck tape along the borders.

You've now left and right polarizing filter slides. Put on 3D glasses of the same making
and determine the orientation in which each pane blocks the light most efficiently by looking
through the filter slide. **Important:** The filter plane that blocks the light on a eye
looking through it directly will be the slide for projection that particular eye later.
The reason for that is, that reflection changes chirality, i.e. left and right turning are
swapped by reflection.

**Setting up the Projection**

1. Align the projectors so that their images match. Vertical alignment must be perfect.
   Horizontal alignment may be slightly shifted, but it should be done as good as possible, to.
2. Place the filters in the light's way. The whole filter area should be used.

Show the stereoscopic material, so that each projector display's its eyes picture.

Comment: Why on Earth would you make this CW?

Comment: By accident... Had that checkbox marked (I presume by tabbing onto it and pressing space).

Comment: Also, this is nothing I had to re-write for StackOverflow, I just copied it from my homepage (which I incidently also manage using markdown)

Comment: Thanks @datenwolf for your great article. I was outside since 2 days.I read above reply thats great..